# Typescript not installed in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a new TypeScript project in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684987/create-a-new-typescript-project-in-visual-studio)

I downloaded and ran the Typescript installer found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790). My dev environment is Win8 + VS2012.

However, there's nothing changed in VS2012 to indicate that the installer ran at all. I tried adding a .ts file into a project, but there was no intellisense. Then I tried poking around if a special project type template was installed, but nothing.

How does one get this to work in VS2012, if at all?

-Thanks for any help!

Comment: [Link](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/12) There is something missing when using MVC4