# Create a new TypeScript project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

How do I start writing TypeScript projects in Visual Studio? There's no option for it when I create a new project. I have Visual Studio 2012 installed along with the TypeScript add on

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I just found the solution: **Manual installation of the VS-Extension.**

In some way, the VS-Extension is not getting installed. You can do it manually. There is a `.vsix` file located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0` called `TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix`.
Try to run this file. It should install the TypeScript extension.

If you are running an x86-based system, try to look at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0`.

Worked for me. Now I can create TypeScript projects and it is listed in the Visual Studio extension list.

Note that the newer versions of TypeScript dropped the folder `0.8.0.0`. You may find the `.vsix` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`.

Comment: That fix worked for me too, on Win 7 x64, VS 2012 Ultimate. Had to use the Search Installed Templates feature to find it though (I'm maybe just not seeing it or need a reboot)

Comment: I had the same problem too with VS 2012 Ultimate on Win 7 32-bit. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I couldn't find the vsix file in the listed directories. Could someone share it please?

Comment: I had the same problem with VS 2012 Ultimate, x64. The vsix file was sitting in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\` (No `0.8.0.0` folder inside there)

Comment: Note that only the 0.8.0 msi has the VSIX file.  you must run the 0.8.0 install, then run the latest version (0.8.3 for me).  I did not have to run the intermediate ones (0.8.1 and 0.8.2)

Answer (score 20):

You can add TypeScript files to an existing project using the Add > New Item dialog.

[image]

You can also create a project of type HTML Application with TypeScript using the Add > New Project dialog. This project type is under Installed->(Templates)->Visual C#.

[image]

If these options are missing from Visual Studio, you should try re-installing the [TypeScript Visual Studio plugin](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=266563).

Comment: I've got the same problem. Reinstalling the TypeScript plugin did not work either. I am using Windows 7 x64 and VS2012.

Comment: I have exactly the same setup as you - Win7 x64, VS2012. What do you have in your list of extensions: `TOOLS > Extensions and Updates`

Comment: Nothing related to TypeScript, except the `Windows Library for JavaScript` which has been there since I installed VS.
Also, if I open a .ts file in VS, there is no syntax highlighting and IntelliSense. TS seems to be completely missing.

Comment: It should be listed as `TypeScript For Microsoft Visual Studio 2012`. Did you close VS when you installed it?

Comment: I just found a solution that worked for me. Take a look at my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshots, that was helpful for finding the path to the HTML project with TypeScript.

Comment: Note: the file extension does not appear in the Add New File dialog for many people. If that happens you may have to reinstall the file extension which you can find here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0

Comment: I would have given up on TypeScript if I hadn't found this thread.
What did it for me was to type in the search box "Typescript". I swear I could not find it in the list.
That's a 8 gig app for you.

Answer (score 16):

If you use Visual Studio 2017, the template 'HTML Application with TypeScript' has been removed from the templates.

But you can install the extension made by rich-newman on Github: https://github.com/rich-newman/typescript-html-application-vs2017-template

To install it do the following:

- Go to the 'Add New Project' window
- At the left go to 'online' in the left tree view
- Search for 'TypeScript HTML Application Template'
  [image]
- Install the extension and the template should be available under 'installed --> TypeScript'

Comment: to use it you also need to install IISexpress

Comment: I ended up using this too.  But still I'm thinking:  Why do we not have any "pure" typescript projects at all, that'd just generate the Javascript file which we could use post build to copy into ANY web project.  All common objects will be in one project.  I may also be able to find & use tools that could translate C# models into Typescript thus autogenerating the model part.  I could also use partials to add methods to the models that I could call from Angular controllers thus ensuring functionality is present in the most relevant class. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

Followed the other answers but could not locate TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix after installing TypeScriptSetup.0.8.0.msi on Win7 64 w/ VS 2010.

To install on VS 2010, use [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to open the above msi and extract "TypeScriptLS.vsix_File", remove the trailing _File, and run as usual.

This gives a new TypeScript project template (but not a file template mysteriously), intellisense, code highlighting, etc.

Comment: Also, where is the Typescript project template?

Comment: @RickLove Create a new Visual C# template - "HTML Application with TypeSCript". Any luck with compiling the ts?

Comment: @RickLove When you extract the .msi there is a tsc.exe which you use to compile your ts files if you are on Windows 7 or 8. However, I'm in windows XP and can't use this exe, it fails with the error "The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvct.dll" Any ideas?

Comment: I am using tsc.exe: I created a console app to run it. I'm using Windows 7. No idea for windows XP.

Comment: Hi Rick, tsc.exe won't work on XP, but for anyone else who sees this, you can compile your Typescript on XP using Windows Script Host like this:
cscript path/to/tsc.js source-file.ts

You can find tsc.js on the cab file within TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix

Comment: @Recursieve thanks so much for that insight! I needed to dynamically compile some typscript on a client machine at runtime who uses xp and this totally just saved me.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the project and ts file templates also, tried reinstalling it(just by running vsix file) that didn't help, so I 
1. uninstalled(from the VS2012 manager) the extension
2. closed VS2012 and then installed it again and voila- 
the Project and file template magically appeared. Thank god it worked- I can start playing with the language without having to run transcompilation manually every time.

Answer (score 0):

Installing typescript adds a new project type as well as adds a file type for existing projects. After installing typescript, you can try searching "typescript" in the new project window. It shows "HTML Application with TypeScript" to me.

Every .ts file typescript file will add a dependent .js file.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Old post, new suggestion:

I've spent a few hours on this issue on Win8/VS2012. After multiple install/reinstall (of Typescript plugin v 0.8.3), the one thing that worked, was to **run VS2012 in Administrator mode** and (re)install **Web Essentials 2012**. That did the trick for me and I got Typescript as it's own section in `Add New Project...` (and all the other goodies mentioned above).

What reminded me of the *run in admin mode* was the process to update documentation (if you want to install documentation locally) where it too had an annoying cryptic error. Running in admin mode was also the answer.

You don't have to run in admin mode all the time, just probably a good practice when updating the IDE itself (new plugins, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

For version 0.9.1.1 I was able to make it work following the instructions here: http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save.

Support for Typescript was just disabled on Web Essentials 2012 3.0: http://vswebessentials.com/changelog

Answer (score 0):

Another tip - you need to install Visual Studio for Web. It will not work with just VS for Desktop. Also, you need to install the plugin after VS, so if you installed the plugin first, uninstall it then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I spent days on this issue too. Eventually found this (very old) answer. Didn't quite help. I have VS 2022 and under Extensions/ Manage Extensions, searched for Typescript and found 'Typescript HTML Application Template'. Downloaded it, created project from it, set the start page and it all seems to work :-)

It was also a simple matter to add a tsconfig.json file. (Not forgetting to put a "dom" in the "lib" line: Mine was
"lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],