# TypeScript IntelliSense not working in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

So I have the typescript extension installed and I can see the new project type ("HTML App with  TypeScript" and the ".ts" file type). Everything seems to work (compilation, error highlighting etc.) but I am not able to get IntelliSense to work correctly. 
Hovering over a parameter displays its type but code completion and "list members" do not work. Doesn't matter if I press `Strg + Space` or select `List Members` from the menu, nothing happens.

I tried to disable/enable "auto list members" in the options, I even reset all the options. 
IntelliSense works fine in C# projects and it even works fine in the .js file that is generated.

Comment: I would suggest filing a bug on the CodePlex project. http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: Did you install the TypeScript VSIX?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684987/create-a-new-typescript-project-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 4):

This is a wicked little Visual Studio issue.  You need the leading "<" for this to work.

```
WRONG way to add a .ts reference:
/// reference path="myOtherFile.ts" />

RIGHT way:
/// <reference path="myOtherFile.ts" />
```

VS 2012 drops in the WRONG text when you drag a file from the solution explorer tree into a text file.  Easily fixed but hard to notice the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit embarrassed on this one, but after about 4 hours of uninstalling/re-installing, re-booting etc... I looked at the references and noticed something strange:

When I drag a `.d.ts` (or any `.ts` file for that manner) I get this:

```
/// reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

Which is incorrect. Notice that this is an XML-comment and needs an opening tag `<`. I changed to the this:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

And suddenly everything started working great.

Answer (score 1):

This is very odd. Can you post some examples of places where you'd expect the completion list to show up, but it doesn't?

Just a sanity check, you don't see any members after typing the dot here?

```
var n = 3;
n.
```

If that doesn't work, please do file a bug on the CodePlex project.

Comment: No, I don't see any members there. The only thing that happens, is that the dot gets underlined after a second because of the error "Expected identifier following dot" but IntelliSense does not work. If I hover over "n" it shows the tooltip "number".

Answer (score 1):

The issue to my problem was disabling Typescript Intellisense in Resharper. See [this blog](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/12/03/solved-intellisense-working-typescript-resharper-installed-using-visual-studio-2012/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after an Internet search found this stackoverflow question.
But then <strike>my box crashed</strike>  I restarted my OS and then IntelliSense started to work.
My answer was to restart OS as well as VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by the MySQL Visual Studio extension. Try uninstalling it and see if the problem is still there.

https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/24