# Visual Studio 2012 Premium SP1 not working with TypeScript plugin

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have **Visual Studio 2012 Premium** installed, and updated to SP1. I have just installed the **TypeScript 8.1.1 plugin** for Visual Studio, but it's not working.

I can create TypeScript files, but they display as plain text (no syntax coloring or intellisense). Also I cannot create TypeScript projects! Disappointed with this, as I have this working on another machine!

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: Did you have another version of type script installed?

Comment: @Flores...nope! I have resolved it...I will give answer in a bit

Comment: SP1 has not yet been released for Visual Studio 2012. Do you either mean **Update 1** for Visual Studio 2012 or SP1 for Visual Studio **2010**?

Comment: @AllonGuralnek, Yes I believe I may mean Update, not SP. Feel free to edit this Q/A if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684987/create-a-new-typescript-project-in-visual-studio).

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Download and install the [TypeScript plugin for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790).
2. Install the TypeScript Language Service

On x64 machines, this is located here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.x.x\TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix

On x86 machines, this is located here:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.x.x\TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix

Now you should be able to create TypeScript projects from visual studio. You should also have the benefit of Intellisense for TypeScript, and automatic compilation to JavaScript and minified JavaScript.

Comment: You think this would run automatically during install.. or alter popup and tell you to do it.  Sigh...

Comment: @Jonesie...absolutely! So it should. Alas...Microsoft failed somewhat on this!

Comment: @MimiEAM, You're missing TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix?

Comment: @series0ne after installing the .msi ,  there is no TypeScriptLanguageService.vsix anywhere

Comment: @MimiEAM did you install both 0.8.0.0 and 0.8.1.1 plugin versions? - this seems to work for me