# VS2012 hangs when having TypeScript items in it

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I downloaded and installed TypeScript 0.8.2 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790 to be used within VS2012 Ultimate edition running in a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise (2 Intel Xeon @ 2.13GHz, 8 GB)

After adding a TypeScript file to it, when I reopen the solution VS 2012 displays the messages "(initializing)" and hangs

Why I think it might be related with TypeScript? If I create the same project with no typescript files in it, just keeping the other files; it always works fine

Am I missing something?
Any help will be very appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the same page you [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790) to:

> "Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows 8"

This is really more a user issue than a programming query, and the [MS forums](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions) might be a better place for it than SO (in particular [this thread](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/397600), which ironically links back to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687882/1014822), and may have a fix for you), but it looks like your OS is not supported.

Comment: You're right about supported OS, I really did not notice/read it. I'm going to ask the TypeScript guys about this.