# Typescript extension not working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I have installed Typescript extension in VS2013 but when I try to create new project from TypeScript templates I am offered only with 'Install Tools for Apache Cordova' template and when I try to add new file to the project I am not offered with Typescript file type. Also, when I open .ts file VS does not recognize the extension. 
I have installed Web Essentials and Typescript 1.4. What did I miss?

Comment: Could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684987/create-a-new-typescript-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: Does not seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that you installed Typescript 1.4, do you mean that you installed [Typescript 1.4 for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304)? Not sure if it is exactly the same.

Comment: Thats the one I have installed.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem.  None of the answers fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, you need to:

1. Repair your Visual Studio 2013.
2. Uninstall Typescript 1.4 extension.
3. Install it again.

Everything will be fine.